# What does Class.getName() do for a given class?

Tags: java, reflection

Suppose i have an class "employee" having an object obj.
then how  the obj.getClass().getName() statement will be performed ? And what it should be return ?

Comment: The object it returns is an Object?  Or any subclass of Object?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. Add some details so one can understand what you are looking for...

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "how will [a statement] be executed?".  Are you asking about how the JVM performs dynamic dispatch at runtime?  How the compiler generates bytecode?  Or simply how to write code that will cause this to be called (though the latter seems trivially straightforward)?

Comment: I don't understand this your question. Is obj an instance of the employee class? Or is it a member variable of an employee? Or something else?

Answer (score 22):

The `getClass()` method gets the actual class of the object, which may be different from the class of the variable holding the object. The `getName()` method will return the full package plus class name of that class as a string, like this:

`com.company.project.package.MyClass`

For example, the following code outputs the above String:

```
package com.company.project.package;

class MyClass extends Object {
  // some definition
}

Object o = new MyClass();
System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());
```

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: While Erick's answer is correct, its not full.

**In short**

This method is similar to *getCanonicalName()* with a difference - it returns binary name of the class, where canonical version returns null (e.g. for anonymous classes).

**Details**

If this class object represents a reference type that is not an array type then the binary name of the class is returned:

```
String.class.getName()
    returns "java.lang.String"
(new Object() {}).getClass().getName()
    returns "test.Main$1"
```

If this class object represents a primitive type or void, then the name returned is a String equal to the Java language keyword corresponding to the primitive type or void.

```
byte.class.getName()
    returns "byte"
long.class.getName()
    returns "long"
```

If this class object represents a class of arrays, then the internal form of the name consists of the name of the element type preceded by one or more '[' characters representing the depth of the array nesting:

```
(new Object[3]).getClass().getName()
    returns "[Ljava.lang.Object;"
(new int[3][4][5][6][7][8][9]).getClass().getName()
    returns "[[[[[[[I"
```

The encoding of element type names is as follows:

```
Element Type           Encoding
boolean                Z
byte                   B
char                   C
class or interface     L<classname>;
double                 D
float                  F
int                    I
long                   J
short                  S
```

Official docs on this method: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--

Answer (score -2):

The name of the class, in your case "employee" or "my.package.employee".